Why does the order of std::chrono::floor matter here?
This works:
  year_month_day day() {
    return year_month_day(floor<days>(
            zoned_time{
              zone,
              system_clock::now()
            }.get_local_time()));
  }

But I need to floor() the zoned_time, as above - since that's templated on the duration, I'd expect to be able to floor either that, or the result of now(), i.e. do this:
  year_month_day day2() {
    return year_month_day(
            zoned_time{
              zone,
              floor<days>(system_clock::now())
            }.get_local_time());
  }

So I'm puzzled as to why I get the following error when I try that - should the zoned_time above not be in units of days, and so fine to convert to a year_month_day?
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::chrono::year_month_day::year_month_day(std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::duration<long int> >)’
   48 |             }.get_local_time());

I'm using g++ (GCC) 14.2.1 20240912 (Red Hat 14.2.1-3) (called as c++) with -std=gnu++20.

What compiler are you using? What version of it? What flags and options do you pass to the compiler? And please copy-paste the full and complete build output into your question.

Re: "But I need to floor() the zoned_time" - You are flooring the zoned_time in your first example.

Added the compiler version/flags, and clarified that I did mean that, I just wonder why I need to do it, I don't have the option of flooring the other thing I expect to floor.

You'll need to convert back to a time point, zoned_time isn't constructible from a duration https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time/zoned_time

While the value of the zoned_time may internally be a 'year month day', there is still no matching constructor of year_month_day that takes a local_time. You still need to convert it in order to have it acceptable for the constructor.

year_month_day can convert from a time point with a precision of days.  That time point can be based on system_clock or local_t.  But in either case, it must have a precision of days.
The reverse conversion can also be made, and when done, results in exactly the same time point as the original.  This is known as a lossless conversion.  Information is conserved.
If conversions were allowed from a time point with precision finer than days, say seconds, then this would be a lossy conversion and break one of the fundamental design principles of chrono: You can't loose information implicitly.  You must explicitly request a lossy conversion with expressions such as floor.
This sub-expression:
floor<days>(system_clock::now())

creates a days-precision time_point based on system_clock.  So far so good.
This sub-expression:
zoned_time{
          zone,
          floor<days>(system_clock::now())
        }.get_local_time()

takes that days-precision time_point and adds the associated time_zone's UTC offset to it to compute the local time.  The UTC offset from the IANA time zone database has units of seconds.  And if you add seconds to a days-precision time_point the result is a seconds-precision time_point.  And this seconds-precision time_point can not be directly converted to a year_month_day.
All of the above is the type system turning a potential run-time error into a compile-time error.  If the lossy conversion were allowed, it would sometimes give the wrong answer.
For example, let's say the UTC offset is 5h, and the current system_clock time of day (UTC) is 20h.  The correct local time (before the floor) is 01:00 the next day:  floor<days>(20h + 5h) gives the next day.
But if one instead computed floor<days>(20h) + 5h you would get 05:00 of the same day (one-off error).

I am curious if there is a way to make chrono library fail in these cases with an explicit error message something like "implicit conversion disabled because it would be lossy. Use explicit cast to .. ".  Hmm I thought = delete(reason)  was added to the standard , but it seems it has been postponed to C++ 26 https://wg21.link/P2573R2

Might get overly verbose.  Maybe = delete(reason) could contain a link to this answer. :-)

Ah, that makes sense now - thanks very much! :)

@HowardHinnant haha that's actually a very good ideea

You're instantiating the zoned_time without specifying the template arguments, which means its deduction guides will be used. In this case the deduction guide is:
template<class TimeZonePtrOrName, class Duration>
zoned_time( TimeZonePtrOrName&&, std::chrono::sys_time<Duration> )
    -> zoned_time<std::common_type_t<Duration, std::chrono::seconds>, /* ... */>;

This gives zoned_time a resolution of at least seconds, which means your resolution of days will be overridden. This is not an issue in your first solution in which the floor is applied later.
Note that even if this compiled (or if you explicitly specified the template parameter), this would be incorrect, because by stripping the hour and minute information, you're preventing the time zone calculation from working properly.
